# Process cube from TSQL

Tags: t-sql, xmla

What is the way in TSQL to run the XMLA code to process a cube

XMLA:

```
<Process xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Object>
    <DatabaseID>Adventure Works DW</DatabaseID>
  </Object>
  <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
  <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
</Process>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this way:

1. Create a new Job in SQL and put the XMLA statement in a *SQL Server Analisys Services Command*
2. Execute this job from your sp with:

`exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job` 'Job Name'